# На какую максимальную степень K делится число N! через разложение на простые множители

Tags: python, простые-числа, теория-чисел

В интернете увидел способ решения  задачи, но никак не могу понять, как работает разложение на множители. Число k раскладываем на множители вида "число - степень", а после делим простые числа на числа от 2 до N. Но я не понимаю, как работает это "деление". Привожу пример своей программы, не могу увидеть, в чем ошибка. Число K уже разложено на множители моим другим алгоритмом, не вижу смысла занимать этим место :

```
d = {}
prostye_chisla.sort()  ##Список с простыми множителями K
for i in l:
    d[i]=l.count(i)  ##Словарь типа "Простое число - степень"
dic = [a * 0 for a in range(len(d))]  


for i in range(2, n+1):
    a = 0
    for j in d:
        if i%j == 0:
            dic[a] += i // j  ##Деление простых множителей на числа от 2 до N
        a+=1

d = list(d.values())
d.reverse()
ans = []
for i in range(len(d)):
    ans.append(dic[i]//d[i])
print(min(ans))  ##Минимум из отношений суммы степеней при простых числах к значению их степеней в основании.
```

Пример, найденный мной : **N = 12, K = 12**.

Раскладываем K на множители : **2^2 * 3^1**. Проверяем, сколько раз числа от 2 до N делятся на эти простые числа : 2 делится 1 раз на два `(1,0)`, 3 делится один раз на 3 `(1,1)`, 4 делится 2 раза на два `(3,1)` 5 не делится и т.д...

Должно получится после всех вычислений `(10,4)`. Затем выбрать минимум из отношений суммы степеней при простых числах к значению их степеней в основании : `min (10/2, 4/1)`

Comment: А приведите для полноты картины кокретный не совсем тривиальный пример? Просто чтобы было проще въехать в задачу?

Comment: Ваша программа работает? Если нет, то на каких входных данных?

Comment: @S.H пример дополнил

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, моя программа судя по всему неправильно проверяет, сколько раз числа от 2 до N делятся на простые числа K. Например, n=5, k=10 вычисляет правильно, но многое остальное - нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В куске вашего кода ниже `i` - множитель из `n!`, `j` - простое число, `dic[a]` накапливает степень простого `j`. Ожидается что `i!` делится на `j^dic[a]` и не делится на `j^(dic[a] + 1)`.

```
    if i%j == 0:
        dic[a] += i // j  ##Деление простых множителей на числа от 2 до N
```

Пусть для примера `i = 256`, `j = 2`. Так как `i` делится на `j^8`, то значение `dic[a]` должно возрасти на `8`. Ваш код добавит `128`, что намного больше.

Поправить можно так:

```
    k = i
    while k % j == 0:
        dic[a] += 1   # увеличиваем степень простого `j` на единицу
        k //= j       # убираем один множитель `j` из `k`
```

**P.S.** Почитайте про [разложение факториала на простые множители](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8) чтобы понять как надо было решать задачу.

```
def prime_factors(n):
    i = 2
    j = n
    while i * i <= j:
        if j % i == 0:
            p = 0
            while j % i == 0:
                j //= i
                p += 1
            yield i, p
        i += 1 if i == 2 else 2
    if j > 1:
        yield j, 1


def factorial_exponent(n, p):
    # assert is_prime(p)
    s = 0
    t = n // p
    while t > 0:
        s += t
        t //= p
    return s


def exponents(k, n):
    for p, e in prime_factors(k):
        yield factorial_exponent(n, p) // e

            
def main():
    k, n = map(int, input().split())
    assert k > 1
    print(min(exponents(k, n)))


main()
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! И еще в большей степени - за полный код! Вот так смотришь, и сразу ошибки всплывают :)